# Are these books still up to code?

Tags: electrical

Hi I reference these books a lot since and for probably way too long. Are they still up to code 
B&d guide to home wiring - copyright 2005
Tauton’s by Rex cauldwell - copyright 2002[image]

Comment: They probably weren't as soon as they made it off the press. That doesn't mean they're not useful.

Comment: I will say that "for pros by pros" book is great for getting an overall understanding of home electrical.  Even if something is out of date according to new code, I'm sure a good 90% is still totally valid and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get new books. The Code has been updated numerous times since the books were published. Circuit protection has really changed along with all switch locations needing neutrals to accommodate smart switches.

Comment: That's about it though, no? [Everything has to be either gfci or afci.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/75166/23295) The only thing I'd use those books for is the charts (ampacity, fills, de-rates, etc.), which I presume haven't changed.

Comment: @Mazura YAH, that's about it. I still keep mine.  I like the pictures and am still waiting to find a job site that's as clean as the pictures in the books..lol... like looking at pictures on a menu... and then seeing what they actually bring you..

Answer (score 4):

No, the NEC is revised every 3 years, at very least GFCI, AFCI, and service disconnect requirements will be out of date.

Comment: That said, you need to ask your permits people ("Authority Having Jurisdiction") what version of the NEC they're working from. (And if they intend to change soon.)

Comment: Are these good ones to use still or are there better manuals out there for do-it-yourselfers like myself

Comment: @Aloysius I considered that aspect, but resolved that no matter what version his local jurisdiction has adopted those books don't reflect current code.